# Setting Intent Context From Multiple Activites

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

I have a class that can be accessed from 2 different activities. Inside this class there is a method that creates an intent to start a different activity. I am passing the context from one activity to the class for use in several methods. The other methods seem to work fine as far as Toast. Once it gets to the method with the intent occurs, I get a crash. According to Logcat it occurs where the intent context is set (212). The error at 211 is where new intent is created.

SplashActivity

```
Parsers parsers=new Parsers(SplashActivity.this);
            parsers.kickoff();
```

Parsers class

```
public class Parsers extends Activity  {
    Context context;

    public Parsers(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        }

public void kickoff(){
//do stuff here that leads to goHome
}

public  void goHome() {
        Log.i("SCROLLS ", "IN GO HOME");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

I know I could create a constructor for each activity name such as

```
 SplashActivity splashactivity;
     public Parsers(SplashActivity splashactivity) {
                this.splashactivity= splashactivity;
                }

 OtherActivity otheractivity;
     public Parsers(OtherActivity otheractivity) {
                this.otheractivity= otheractivity;
                }
```

This would do little since the intent context needs to change depending on which activity is using the class.  Am I not passing the context properly to the class or just missing something else?

Logcat Line:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
at com.yaadspice.myapp.Model.Parsers.goHome(Parsers.java:212)

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
at com.yaadspice.epgtv.Model.Parsers.goHome(Parsers.java:211)
```

Comment: "According to Logcat"
Maybe you wanna post that.

Comment: Edited to add logcat line where crash occurs. This line is where the startActivity(intent) occurs.

Comment: inside `goHome()` use `context` to create `Intent` instead of `this`. Do you need `Parser` class to `extend Activity`?

Comment: post the logcat

Comment: @android_hub-using the context in stead of this and not extending Activity fixed it. I did have to add qualifier context at startActivity(intent) but it worked.  If you post the answer I'll accept.